# C program not printing outputs after inputs are gathered

Tags: c

So I am writing the following code for a final project for class. I am using onlinegdb as the compiler as I could not get visual basic to run c. The program runs without any errors but after I put inputs in the program never prints the output of avghits. The code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int attackingUnitSize, skill, strength, armorPenetration, attacks, damage= 0;
    int defendingUnitSize, toughness, save, invulnerableSave = 0;
    int woundRoll, saveRoll, simulations = 0;
    int hitSimulations, woundSimulations, saveSimulations = 0;
    int dice, successfulHits, successfulWounds, successfulSaves = 0;
    int hitDiceResults[hitSimulations], woundDiceResults[successfulHits];
    int saveDiceResults[successfulWounds];
    int hitOnes, hitTwos, hitThrees, hitFours, hitFives, hitSixes = 0;
    int woundOnes, woundTwos, woundThrees, woundFours, woundFives, woundSixes = 0;
    int saveOnes, saveTwos, saveThrees, saveFours, saveFives, saveSixes = 0;
    double avgHits, avgWounds, avgSaves = 0;
    
    srand(time(0));
    
    printf("This program will ask for characteristics from warhammer 40k and ");
    printf("ask how many simulations you would like to run.\nIt will output the");
    printf(" average amount of successful hit rolls, wound rolls, damage and ");
    printf("save rolls made.\n");
    
    /*States that attacking units characteristics will be entered first*/
    printf("Enter the attacking units characteristics.\n");
    
    /*Gets unit size*/
    printf("Enter the units size: ");
    scanf("%d", &attackingUnitSize);
    
    /*Gets weapon/ballistic skill*/
    printf("Enter units weapon skill(WS) or ballistic skill(BS): ");
    scanf("%d", &skill);
    
    /*Gets units strength*/
    printf("Enter units strength(S): ");
    scanf("%d", &strength);
    
    /*Gets armor penetration*/
    printf("Enter units armor penetration(AP): ");
    scanf("%d", &armorPenetration);
    
    /*Gets number of attacks*/
    printf("Enter number of attacks: ");
    scanf("%d", &attacks);
    
    /*Gets damage*/
    printf("Enter the damage of the weapon: ");
    scanf("%d", &damage);
    
    /*States that defending units characteristics will be entered now*/
    printf("Enter the defending units characteristics.\n");
    
    /*Gets defending unit size*/
    printf("Enter units size: ");
    scanf("%d", &defendingUnitSize);
    
    /*Gets defending units toughness*/
    printf("Enter defending units toughness: ");
    scanf("%d", &toughness);
    
    /*Gets defending units save*/
    printf("Enter units Save: ");
    scanf("%d", &save);
    
    /*Gets defending units invulnerable save, if applicable*/
    printf("Enter defending units invulnerable save(if none, enter: 0): ");
    scanf("%d", &invulnerableSave);
    
    /*Gets number of simulations*/
    printf("How many simulations would you like to be done? ");
    scanf("%d", &simulations);

    /*Determines the lowest value for the wound roll*/
    if (strength >= (toughness * 2)){
        woundRoll = 2;
    }
    else if ((strength > toughness) && (strength < ((toughness * 2)))){
        woundRoll = 3;
    }
    else if (strength == toughness){
        woundRoll = 4;
    }
    else if ((strength < toughness) && ((strength * 2) > toughness)){
        woundRoll = 5;
    }
    else{
        woundRoll = 6;
    }
    
    /* Determines which save characterist to use */
    save += armorPenetration;
    if (invulnerableSave != 0){
        if (save < invulnerableSave){
            saveRoll = save;
        }
        else{
            saveRoll = invulnerableSave;
        }
    }
    else if(save > 6){
        saveRoll = 7;
    }
    else{
        saveRoll = save;
    }
    
    // Determines how many attacks are done and multiples that by simulations 
    attacks *= attackingUnitSize;
    hitSimulations = simulations * attacks;

    int i, j, k;
    for (i = 0; i < hitSimulations; i++){
        dice = rand() % 6 + 1;
        hitDiceResults[i] = dice;
      /*  printf("%d ", diceResults[i]); intended for debugging*/
    }
    
    //gets the number of hits for each dice face
    for (i = 0; i < hitSimulations; i++){
        if (hitDiceResults[i] == 1){
            hitOnes += 1;
        }
        else if (hitDiceResults[i] == 2){
            hitTwos += 1;
        }
        else if (hitDiceResults[i] == 3){
            hitThrees += 1;
        }
        else if (hitDiceResults[i] == 4){
            hitFours += 1;
        }
        else if (hitDiceResults[i] == 5){
            hitFives += 1;
        }
        else {
            hitSixes += 1;
        }
    }
    
    // Tallies up successful hits
    if (skill == 1){
        successfulHits = hitOnes + hitTwos + hitThrees + hitFours + hitFives + hitSixes;
        }
    else if (skill == 2){
        successfulHits = hitTwos + hitThrees + hitFours + hitFives + hitSixes;
        }
    else if (skill == 3){
        successfulHits = hitThrees + hitFours + hitFives + hitSixes;
        }
    else if (skill == 4){
        successfulHits = hitFours + hitFives + hitSixes;
        }
    else if (skill == 5){
        successfulHits = hitFives + hitSixes;
        }
    else {
        successfulHits = hitSixes;
        }

    //rolls dice for wounds after successful hits
    for(j = 0; j < successfulHits; j++){
        dice = rand() % 6 + 1;
        woundDiceResults[j] = dice;
    }
    
    //tallies up the wounds for each dice face
    for(j = 0; j < successfulHits; j++){
        if (woundDiceResults[j] == 1){
            woundOnes += 1;
        }
        else if (woundDiceResults[j] == 2){
            woundTwos += 1;
        }
        else if (woundDiceResults[j] == 3){
            woundThrees += 1;
        }
        else if (woundDiceResults[j] == 4){
            woundFours += 1;
        }
        else if (woundDiceResults[j] == 5){
            woundFives += 1;
        }
        else {
            woundSixes += 1;
        }
    }
    
        //tallies up the successful wound rolls
        if (woundRoll == 1){
            successfulWounds = woundOnes + woundTwos + woundThrees + woundFours + woundFives + woundSixes;
        }
        else if (woundRoll == 2){
            successfulWounds = woundTwos + woundThrees + woundFours + woundFives + woundSixes;
        }
        else if (woundRoll == 3){
            successfulWounds = woundThrees + woundFours + woundFives + woundSixes;
        }
        else if (woundRoll == 4){
            successfulWounds = woundFours + woundFives + woundSixes;
        }
        else if (woundRoll == 5){
            successfulWounds = woundFives + woundSixes;
        }
        else {
            successfulWounds = woundSixes;
        }
        
    //rolls dice equal to the number of successfulwounds    
    for (k = 0; k < successfulWounds; k++){
        dice = rand() % 6 + 1;
        saveDiceResults[k] = dice;
    }
    
    // tallies up the saves for each dice face rolled
    for(k = 0; k < successfulHits; k++){
        if (saveDiceResults[k] == 1){
            saveOnes += 1;
        }
        else if (saveDiceResults[k] == 2){
            saveTwos += 1;
        }
        else if (saveDiceResults[k] == 3){
            saveThrees += 1;
        }
        else if (saveDiceResults[k] == 4){
            saveFours += 1;
        }
        else if (saveDiceResults[k] == 5){
            saveFives += 1;
        }
        else {
            saveSixes += 1;
        }
    }
    
    if (saveRoll == 1){
        successfulSaves = saveOnes + saveTwos + saveThrees + saveFours + saveFives + saveSixes;
    }
    else if (saveRoll == 2){
        successfulSaves = saveTwos + saveThrees + saveFours + saveFives + saveSixes;
    }
    else if (saveRoll == 3){
        successfulSaves = saveThrees + saveFours + saveFives + saveSixes;
    }
    else if (saveRoll == 4){
        successfulSaves = saveFours + saveFives + saveSixes;
    }
    else if (saveRoll == 5){
        successfulSaves = saveFives + saveSixes;
    }
    else {
        successfulSaves = saveSixes;
    }
    
    /*Debugging
        printf("Hit rolls of 1 rolled: %d\n", hitOnes);
        printf("Hit rolls of 2 rolled: %d\n", hitTwos);
        printf("Hit rolls of 3 rolled: %d\n", hitThrees);
        printf("Hit rolls of 4 rolled: %d\n", hitFours);
        printf("Hit rolls of 5 rolled: %d\n", hitFives);
        printf("Hit rolls of 6 rolled: %d\n", hitSixes);
        */

    avgHits = successfulHits / simulations;
    printf("Average number of hits across %d simulations ", simulations);
    printf(" is: %f.\n", avgHits);
    
    return 0;
}
```

I want to solve this issue before I continue to write the rest of the code. I was expecting it to print the results but nothing happens after the number of simulations is entered. I cannot figure out what is causing this as this is the first time I have encountered this issue. Any advice on how to fix would be great.

Comment: When you do the definition `int hitDiceResults[hitSimulations], ...` what is the value of `hitSimulations`? Unless you say *indeterminate* it's wrong.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude it is indeterminate, because I want the user to determine how many simulations they would like to run.

Comment: As for the program itself, didn't you test the code as you were writing it? Don't write large pieces of code, or even whole programs, all in one go without building (with extra warnings enabled, treated as errors) and testing. Only write, build and test small pieces of code, and make sure it builds cleanly and passes all tests before continuing with the next small piece.

Comment: So how will the program know how many elements should be in the array, at that point in the program? When you define a variable, it's done in the order written. Variables aren't redefined at a later time.

Comment: You *must* check the user inputs.  If you write `scanf("%d", &foo)` and the user enters 'A', your program needs to respond appropriately.  Especially if you are not initializing your variables.  You *must* check the return value of `scanf`.  Every time.

Comment: Also note that when I say that the value is indeterminate, it means that there is no initialized value of `hitSimulations` (and most of your other variables). You don't give it an explicit value until later in the program. Most notably, its value will *not* be equal to zero (unless by chance, because you don't initialize it to zero).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I did test individual parts to confirm they were working before continuing.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude got it. Makes sense now. As i was checking this before it ran fine without the arrays being initialized

Comment: @WilliamPursell I will add in checks to make the code more robust.

Answer (score 0):

A few things

1. Variable length arrays have been [controversial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) in C. so do not use them instead please use dynamic memory allocation like `malloc();`
2. You are trying to define the array size from a variable whose value you get at runtime. This is a logical error. You have to move the definition after calculating the values of `hitDiceResults`, `woundDiceResults`, `saveDiceResults`.
3. Please see my code changes which are highlighted by `//<- code changed here`

   ```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <time.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    int main()
    {
        int attackingUnitSize, skill, strength, armorPenetration, attacks, damage= 0;
        int defendingUnitSize, toughness, save, invulnerableSave = 0;
        int woundRoll, saveRoll, simulations = 0;
        int hitSimulations, woundSimulations, saveSimulations = 0;
        int dice, successfulHits, successfulWounds, successfulSaves = 0;

        int hitOnes, hitTwos, hitThrees, hitFours, hitFives, hitSixes = 0;
        int woundOnes, woundTwos, woundThrees, woundFours, woundFives, woundSixes = 0;
        int saveOnes, saveTwos, saveThrees, saveFours, saveFives, saveSixes = 0;
        double avgHits, avgWounds, avgSaves = 0;

        int* hitDiceResults; //<- code changed here
        int* woundDiceResults; //<- code changed here
        int* saveDiceResults; //<- code changed here

        srand(time(0));

        printf("This program will ask for characteristics from warhammer 40k and ");
        printf("ask how many simulations you would like to run.\nIt will output the");
        printf(" average amount of successful hit rolls, wound rolls, damage and ");
        printf("save rolls made.\n");

        /*States that attacking units characteristics will be entered first*/
        printf("Enter the attacking units characteristics.\n");

        /*Gets unit size*/
        printf("Enter the units size: ");
        scanf("%d", &attackingUnitSize);

        /*Gets weapon/ballistic skill*/
        printf("Enter units weapon skill(WS) or ballistic skill(BS): ");
        scanf("%d", &skill);

        /*Gets units strength*/
        printf("Enter units strength(S): ");
        scanf("%d", &strength);

        /*Gets armor penetration*/
        printf("Enter units armor penetration(AP): ");
        scanf("%d", &armorPenetration);

        /*Gets number of attacks*/
        printf("Enter number of attacks: ");
        scanf("%d", &attacks);

        /*Gets damage*/
        printf("Enter the damage of the weapon: ");
        scanf("%d", &damage);

        /*States that defending units characteristics will be entered now*/
        printf("Enter the defending units characteristics.\n");

        /*Gets defending unit size*/
        printf("Enter units size: ");
        scanf("%d", &defendingUnitSize);

        /*Gets defending units toughness*/
        printf("Enter defending units toughness: ");
        scanf("%d", &toughness);

        /*Gets defending units save*/
        printf("Enter units Save: ");
        scanf("%d", &save);

        /*Gets defending units invulnerable save, if applicable*/
        printf("Enter defending units invulnerable save(if none, enter: 0): ");
        scanf("%d", &invulnerableSave);

        /*Gets number of simulations*/
        printf("How many simulations would you like to be done? ");
        scanf("%d", &simulations);

        /*Determines the lowest value for the wound roll*/
        if (strength >= (toughness * 2)){
            woundRoll = 2;
        }
        else if ((strength > toughness) && (strength < ((toughness * 2)))){
            woundRoll = 3;
        }
        else if (strength == toughness){
            woundRoll = 4;
        }
        else if ((strength < toughness) && ((strength * 2) > toughness)){
            woundRoll = 5;
        }
        else{
            woundRoll = 6;
        }

        /* Determines which save characterist to use */
        save += armorPenetration;
        if (invulnerableSave != 0){
            if (save < invulnerableSave){
                saveRoll = save;
            }
            else{
                saveRoll = invulnerableSave;
            }
        }
        else if(save > 6){
            saveRoll = 7;
        }
        else{
            saveRoll = save;
        }

        // Determines how many attacks are done and multiples that by simulations 
        attacks *= attackingUnitSize;
        hitSimulations = simulations * attacks;
        hitDiceResults = malloc(hitSimulations * sizeof(int)); //<- code changed here

        int i, j, k;
        for (i = 0; i < hitSimulations; i++){
            dice = rand() % 6 + 1;
            hitDiceResults[i] = dice;
          /*  printf("%d ", diceResults[i]); intended for debugging*/
        }

        //gets the number of hits for each dice face
        for (i = 0; i < hitSimulations; i++){
            if (hitDiceResults[i] == 1){
                hitOnes += 1;
            }
            else if (hitDiceResults[i] == 2){
                hitTwos += 1;
            }
            else if (hitDiceResults[i] == 3){
                hitThrees += 1;
            }
            else if (hitDiceResults[i] == 4){
                hitFours += 1;
            }
            else if (hitDiceResults[i] == 5){
                hitFives += 1;
            }
            else {
                hitSixes += 1;
            }
        }

        // Tallies up successful hits
        if (skill == 1){
            successfulHits = hitOnes + hitTwos + hitThrees + hitFours + hitFives + hitSixes;
            }
        else if (skill == 2){
            successfulHits = hitTwos + hitThrees + hitFours + hitFives + hitSixes;
            }
        else if (skill == 3){
            successfulHits = hitThrees + hitFours + hitFives + hitSixes;
            }
        else if (skill == 4){
            successfulHits = hitFours + hitFives + hitSixes;
            }
        else if (skill == 5){
            successfulHits = hitFives + hitSixes;
            }
        else {
            successfulHits = hitSixes;
            }

        woundDiceResults = malloc(successfulHits * sizeof(int));//<- code changed here
        //rolls dice for wounds after successful hits
        for(j = 0; j < successfulHits; j++){
            dice = rand() % 6 + 1;
            woundDiceResults[j] = dice;
        }

        //tallies up the wounds for each dice face
        for(j = 0; j < successfulHits; j++){
            if (woundDiceResults[j] == 1){
                woundOnes += 1;
            }
            else if (woundDiceResults[j] == 2){
                woundTwos += 1;
            }
            else if (woundDiceResults[j] == 3){
                woundThrees += 1;
            }
            else if (woundDiceResults[j] == 4){
                woundFours += 1;
            }
            else if (woundDiceResults[j] == 5){
                woundFives += 1;
            }
            else {
                woundSixes += 1;
            }
        }

            //tallies up the successful wound rolls
            if (woundRoll == 1){
                successfulWounds = woundOnes + woundTwos + woundThrees + woundFours + woundFives + woundSixes;
            }
            else if (woundRoll == 2){
                successfulWounds = woundTwos + woundThrees + woundFours + woundFives + woundSixes;
            }
            else if (woundRoll == 3){
                successfulWounds = woundThrees + woundFours + woundFives + woundSixes;
            }
            else if (woundRoll == 4){
                successfulWounds = woundFours + woundFives + woundSixes;
            }
            else if (woundRoll == 5){
                successfulWounds = woundFives + woundSixes;
            }
            else {
                successfulWounds = woundSixes;
            }

        saveDiceResults = malloc(successfulWounds * sizeof(int)); //<- code changed here
        //rolls dice equal to the number of successfulwounds    
        for (k = 0; k < successfulWounds; k++){
            dice = rand() % 6 + 1;
            saveDiceResults[k] = dice;
        }

        // tallies up the saves for each dice face rolled
        for(k = 0; k < successfulHits; k++){
            if (saveDiceResults[k] == 1){
                saveOnes += 1;
            }
            else if (saveDiceResults[k] == 2){
                saveTwos += 1;
            }
            else if (saveDiceResults[k] == 3){
                saveThrees += 1;
            }
            else if (saveDiceResults[k] == 4){
                saveFours += 1;
            }
            else if (saveDiceResults[k] == 5){
                saveFives += 1;
            }
            else {
                saveSixes += 1;
            }
        }

        if (saveRoll == 1){
            successfulSaves = saveOnes + saveTwos + saveThrees + saveFours + saveFives + saveSixes;
        }
        else if (saveRoll == 2){
            successfulSaves = saveTwos + saveThrees + saveFours + saveFives + saveSixes;
        }
        else if (saveRoll == 3){
            successfulSaves = saveThrees + saveFours + saveFives + saveSixes;
        }
        else if (saveRoll == 4){
            successfulSaves = saveFours + saveFives + saveSixes;
        }
        else if (saveRoll == 5){
            successfulSaves = saveFives + saveSixes;
        }
        else {
            successfulSaves = saveSixes;
        }

        /*Debugging
            printf("Hit rolls of 1 rolled: %d\n", hitOnes);
            printf("Hit rolls of 2 rolled: %d\n", hitTwos);
            printf("Hit rolls of 3 rolled: %d\n", hitThrees);
            printf("Hit rolls of 4 rolled: %d\n", hitFours);
            printf("Hit rolls of 5 rolled: %d\n", hitFives);
            printf("Hit rolls of 6 rolled: %d\n", hitSixes);
            */

        avgHits = successfulHits / simulations;
        printf("Average number of hits across %d simulations ", simulations);
        printf(" is: %f.\n", avgHits);

        free(hitDiceResults); //<- code changed here
        free(woundDiceResults); //<- code changed here
        free(saveDiceResults); //<- code changed here

        return 0;
    }
   ```